# Reading from Socket Stream Blocking After Retrieval

Tags: sockets, ada, gnat

I'm currently attempting to read an incoming message from a client socket, that, prior to the below procedure has already been connected to the server socket. The below procedure outputs the message, one character at a time, as it retrieves it from the stream.

The problem is that, when the stream is out of information, the call to `Ada.Streams.Read` is blocking, and stops the application flow completely. According to some examples, it would appear as though `Offset` should be set to `0` automatically at the end of the stream, but that never happens. Instead the application stops at the call to `Read`.

```ada
procedure Read_From (Channel : Sockets.Stream_Access) is

    use Ada.Text_IO;
    use Ada.Streams;

    Data   : Stream_Element_Array (1 .. 1);
    Offset : Stream_Element_Offset;
begin
    loop
        Read (Channel.All, Data, Offset);
        exit when Offset = 0;
        Put (Character'Val (Data (1)));
    end loop;

    -- The application never reaches this point.

    New_Line;
    Put_Line ("Finished reading from client!");
end Read_From;
-- @param Channel `GNAT.Sockets.Stream (Client_Socket)`
```

I've also attempted the same process with `GNAT.Sockets.Receive_Socket`, but the same issue remains: the application flow is stopped completely, assumably awaiting further information from the stream, even though there is nothing more to retrieve.

Any pointers in the right direction would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried setting a `Receive_Timeout`?

Comment: @egilhh I gave it a shot just now. What happens then is that the connection times out. I am, however, absolutely certain that all the data has been sent, as all the expected data is outputted in the console. One solution I can think of, with that in mind, would be to simply catch the `Socker_Error` that is risen, and use that as a means of determining the end of the stream. That, to me on the other hand, does not seem all too reliable. Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to close the connection from the other end?

Comment: I suspect one can use GNAT.Sockets.Check_Selector (..) to check if there is any more data that has been received on the socket, which means only calling Read (..) when there is data to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you’d read a (binary) message from a stream knowing how much data needed to be read, so you could read until you’d got that much.

But, if you’re reading a text message from an externally-defined source, as it might be an HTTP request, there needs to be some terminator sequence so you can read character-by-character until you’ve read the terminator. In the case of an HTTP request, that’s a CR/LF/CR/LF sequence. Or it could be a null-terminated C string, in which case you’d be looking for the `ASCII.NUL`.

The Ada way to transfer variable-length text is to use `String’Output`/`String’Input` (see [ARM 13.13.2(18)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-13-13-2.html#p18)ff). What happens for a `String` (an array of `Character`) is that first the bounds are sent, then the content; on reception, the bounds are read, a `String` with those bounds is created, and the required number of bytes are read into the new `String`, which is then returned.

Answer (score 2):

Basically that's how Ada streams work.  The end of the stream only comes once you reach the final end of the stream, not just the current end of a buffer.

If you want to be able to interrupt reading, you have to use another representation of the connection than `GNAT.Sockets.Stream_Access`.